# check the continuity of function of several variable.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Check the continuity of the given function at origin:

$$F(x,y)=\frac{\sin (x+y)}{x+y}$$

If we use the expansion of sin and apply the limit we get that limit is $1$ also if we approach the limit along any line passing through origin then again limit is $1$. But, on this basis one can not conclude that function is continuous. I tried to to solve by epsilon-delta definition, could not get the answer.Any help is appreciated. Thnakx in advance.

Comment: Your function isn't even defined at the origin. Perhaps there should be some piecewise definition?

Comment: @ZacharySelk it doesn't need to be defined at the origin for the limit to exist.  It just needs to be defined in the neighborhood.

Comment: Can you use the identity $\sin (x+y) \le (x+y) < \tan (x+y) \implies 1 \ge \frac {\sin (x+y)}{x+y} \ge \cos (x+y)$

Comment: @DougM But the problems asks to check the continuity, which does require it to be defined at the origin. I'm being very nitpicky here I accept.

Comment: @ Zachary Selk Sir Whatever will be the limit we will take the function at (0,0) to that limit.

Comment: @DougM using your identity, by squeeze theorem we can conclude that limit exist and equal to 1. But can you explain about this inequality $\frac {\sin (x+y)}{x+y} \ge \cos (x+y)$ ? I am not getting this.

Comment: Do you understand where $|\sin (x+y)| \le |(x+y)| \le |\tan (x+y)|$ comes from?  It comes from the geometry of the unit cricle.  Divide through by $|\sin (x+y)|.$  Then take the reciprocals.

Comment: "if we approach the limit along any line passing through origin then again limit is 1" What about the line $y=-x?$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
h(t)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin t}{t} & t\ne0,\\1 & t=0.\end{cases}
$$
$h$ is continuous (even analytic) on $\Bbb R$. Then, when defined as $1$ on the line $x+y=0$,
$$
F(x,y)=h(x+y).
$$
$F$ is also continuous because it is the composition of continuous functions